# How do I subtract two datetime in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have one column

1. `ivr_table_time['payment_time']` giving me value like : `2021-11-06 14:00:56.826503`
2. `ivr_table_time['call_time']`  giving me value like: `2021-11-04 18:30:20`

I want to find if payment was done within 15 mins of the call.
I used the following condition - `np.where((ivr_table_time['payment_time'] - ivr_table_time['call_time'])<='00:15:00', 1, 0)`
but I am not getting the correct answer. How do I approach this? Please help.

Comment: For me working nice, can you explin more what means `I am not getting the correct answer` ?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC use:

```
np.where((ivr_table_time['payment_time'] - ivr_table_time['call_time'])<= pd.Timedelta('00:15:00'), 1, 0)
```

Or:

```
(ivr_table_time['payment_time'] - ivr_table_time['call_time']<= pd.Timedelta('00:15:00')).astype(int)
```